# Jmeter - Stop sending requests after certain condition is met using while controller

Tags: java, while-loop, jmeter, conditional-statements

I am creating a jmeter script that picks a value from a previously captured variable called MultitrackeId which can contains "n" values.

[image: MultitrackerId variables]

In the screenshot, for example there are 5 values which are expected to be sent over and over again until "SUCCESSFUL" is present in the response body, I am using a single thread, a counter and a WHILE controller for iterating sequentially like this:

[image: counter]

The counter takes `${miltitrackedid_matchNr}` as the maximum value and it starts in 1 with a 1 increment.this is how the implementation looks in the request:

[image: implementation]

Currently, the WHILE controller has no any conditions so it's being used just for iterate. At this point the thread keeps in a infinite loop sending requests like these:

```
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_1 
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_2 
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_3 
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_4 
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_5
```

and it starts again

```
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_1 
... 
... 
... 
domain/${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})} -->  /multitrackerIdvalue_5
```

I need to loop sequentially as shown for all the multitrackerId values until "SUCCESSFUL" value is found and then stop sending that specific request and wait for the others multitrackerId requests to contains the value in the response to finally stop the thread and end the test.

I have tried to figure out which is the indicated condition, I am currently using_

```
${\__javaScript("${VarStatus}".indexOf("SUCCESSFUL") == -1)}
```

However, this is not a proper solution considering that after the first "SUCCESSFUL" occurrence in the response the thread will stop without having the met conditions for the remaining MultitrackerIds.

Do you have any recommendations or possible approach for solving this ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's built-in test elements are not flexible enough to implement your criteria, you will need to go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and some [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) scripting.

Example setup:

1. Change your While Controller's condition to the following [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${matches} < 5,)}
   ```
2. Put your request which is in the While Controller under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}_skip" != "true",)}
   ```
3. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which might return `SUCCESSFUL` and put the following code there:

   ```
   def matches = vars.getObject('matches') ?: 0

   if (prev.getResponseData().contains('SUCCESSFUL')) {
       vars.putObject('matches', matches + 1)
       def variable = 'multitrackerIdvalue_' + ((vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int) + 1)
       vars.put(variable + '_skip', 'true')
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello, I was able to achieve the first part; however, how each Multitrackerid starts with the status "In Progress" and then transitions to the "Successful" status; some finish quickly with this status, and others take longer. Now, I need to control that if the multitrackerId_1 has the status "Successful," stop asking about it and continue with the other multitrackerIDs in progress status. This part is not working since it repeats those that had this "Successful" status, and it stops when the matches are in 5 and does not consider that some Multitrackerids are in progress.